# Cannot find myself in Stack Overflow rating

Tags: support, profile-page, reputation-leagues, top-users

Why don't I see myself in users rating on Stack Overflow, and don't have top x% rating link? I have 371 reputation, and as I understand I need only 200 to be in rating list.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**TL;DR:** [Caching](http://shouldiblamecaching.com/)

[Four hours ago](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5397625/anton-rodzik?tab=reputation), you had 'only' 191 reputation, and those reputation leagues are cached (for 24 hours? I don't know exactly) because it takes some binary firepower to build them. Just wait for a day and  I'm sure your name will appear in the list.